Python vs Python3 in Windows
I am on a Windows machine. Writing where python in command prompt gives the following
C:\Users\$USERNAME$\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\python.exe

I installed Python manually (via chrome). I also used msys2 for installing gcc and ghdl in the past. It looks like msys2 also installed python for some package. Now the problem is using python in powershell defaults to the windows AppData python but using python3 defaults to msys2 python.

I am guessing I shouldn't uninstall python from msys2 as some packages might depend on it. But I want to make it so that python and python3 both default to the windows AppData python.
If I install some package using pip, I can use it using python but using the package with python3 gives the 'package not found' error. Why is this happening?

I tried reordering my path variables so windows AppData python is above msys2 python, but this didn't solve the problem.

You can certainly change your PATH.  I'm not sure who would be rewriting that in your PowerShell, but it's under your control.

"where" shows all python that are in PATH, "which" the currently used. If you install python through the microsoft store, it'll be automatically added to path. If you download python from the python website and install it, it asks on install if you want to add it to path. Also look into python venv to avoid issues like these more easily

@x3l51 Windows doesn't support which command, it is a UNIX only command. I am aware that python's path is added to path. I want to make sure that python3 uses the path I want. I will look into venv, thanks!

You can also specify the binary used in the shebang line
